# Looking for a book from my childhood about evil plant neighbors

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm having trouble locating a book from my childhood, I owned it somewhere between the mid to late 90's.

The first book I remember was about a kid who gets neighbors who turned out to be evil plants. I think it had something to do with them replacing the main kids' parents with evil plant copies. I remember one part of the book had the kid trapped and some flowers blooming above him and the pollen being poisonous. At the end of the book was a supposed picture of one of these "evil plants" caught in a jar, kinda like they were saying this book was based on real events. I believe this was a series because in the back of the book was an order form for more books by the author.

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Great! Feel free to ask the other one.